# Set minimal spacing between values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, cumsum

I have the following dataframe where the column `value` is sorted:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'variable': {0: 'Chi', 1: 'San Antonio', 2: 'Dallas', 3: 'PHL', 4: 'Houston', 5: 'NY', 6: 'Phoenix', 7: 'San Diego', 8: 'LA', 9: 'San Jose', 10: 'SF'}, 'value': {0: 191.28, 1: 262.53, 2: 280.21, 3: 283.08, 4: 290.75, 5: 295.72, 6: 305.6, 7: 357.89, 8: 380.07, 9: 452.71, 10: 477.67}})
```

Output:

```
       variable   value
0           Chi  191.28
1   San Antonio  262.53
2        Dallas  280.21
3           PHL  283.08
4       Houston  290.75
5            NY  295.72
6       Phoenix  305.60
7     San Diego  357.89
8            LA  380.07
9      San Jose  452.71
10           SF  477.67
```

I want to find values where the distance between neighboring values is smaller than 10:

```
df['value'].diff() < 10
```

Output:

```
0     False
1     False
2     False
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
Name: value, dtype: bool
```

Now I want to equally space those `True` values that are too close to each other. The idea is to take the first value before the `True` sequence (280.21) and add 5 to each next `True` value (cumulative sum): first `True` = 280 + 5, second `True` = 280 + 5 + 5, third `True` = 280 + 5 + 5...

Expected Output:

```
       variable   value
0           Chi  191.28
1   San Antonio  262.53
2        Dallas  280.21 
3           PHL  285.21 <-
4       Houston  290.21 <-
5            NY  295.21 <-
6       Phoenix  300.21 <-
7     San Diego  357.89
8            LA  380.07
9      San Jose  452.71
10           SF  477.67
```

My solution:

```
mask = df['value'].diff() < 10
df.loc[mask, 'value'] = 5
df.loc[mask | mask.shift(-1), 'value'] = last_day[mask | mask.shift(-1), 'value'].cumsum()
```

Maybe there is a more elegant one.

Comment: A little searching on the problem came up with several useful references for [pd.consecutiveCounts] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389287/efficient-method-to-count-consecutive-positive-values-in-pandas-dataframe).  Use that to get your spacing coefficient, the multiplier of `5`.

Comment: Also watch out: what would happen if the value for San Diego were close enough for the spacing to infringe?  For instance, a series of 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 115.

Comment: @Prune I don't understand what this answer has in common with mine. I don't count any values.

Comment: Yes, you do: you're counting consecutive `True` evaluations.

Comment: No. I replace them with an equally spaced sequence. They are not necessarily consecutive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'variable': {0: 'Chi', 1: 'San Antonio', 2: 'Dallas', 3: 'PHL', 4: 'Houston', 5: 'NY', 6: 'Phoenix', 7: 'San Diego', 8: 'LA', 9: 'San Jose', 10: 'SF'}, 'value': {0: 191.28, 1: 262.53, 2: 280.21, 3: 283.08, 4: 290.75, 5: 295.72, 6: 305.6, 7: 357.89, 8: 380.07, 9: 452.71, 10: 477.67}})

s = df['value'].diff() < 10
add_amt = s.cumsum().mask(~s) * 5

df_out = df.assign(value=df['value'].mask(add_amt.notna()).ffill() + add_amt.fillna(0))
df_out
```

Output:

```
       variable   value
0           Chi  191.28
1   San Antonio  262.53
2        Dallas  280.21
3           PHL  285.21
4       Houston  290.21
5            NY  295.21
6       Phoenix  300.21
7     San Diego  357.89
8            LA  380.07
9      San Jose  452.71
10           SF  477.67
```